# How to assign constant boost value for single field in elasticsearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

There are a lot of scoring/boosting options in elasticsearch but I haven't found the possibility to add a constant boost value for particular field. If such option exists, how the mapping should look like? Maybe there is an option to calculate score for the entire document depending on which field is being hit?

Comment: Have you [looked at the es docs on mappings?](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/core-types/) There is a parameter `boost` for most types.

Comment: You're right but I prefer to calculate score on query time instead of index time.

Comment: Ok, you can do that with the `boost` parameter on most query types, [see the `term` query as an example](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/term-query/).

Comment: Or have you seen the [`constant_score` query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/constant-score-query/)?

Comment: Thanks. The problem with boost param is that it does not appear for every query type, for example "text_phrase_prefix". I've found satisfying solution: wrapper-query called "custom_boost_factor" - check my answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution: wrapper query "custom_boost_factor" which multiplies the score of embedded query of every type:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/test/entry/_search?pretty=true' -d '{ 
  "query":{
    "custom_boost_factor" :{
      "query" : {
        "text_phrase_prefix" : {
          "title" : "test"
        }
      },
      "boost_factor": 2.0
    }
  }
}'
```